# Generating Access Toke Causes unauthorized_client

Tags: vba, oauth, authorization

Following the steps in https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token, I'm able to get user authorization consent. However, when I try to get an access token, the following error is returned: { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "unauthorized_client" }. I found similar problems and have followed the recommendations offered, but non seem to apply. I'm using the following VBA code:

```
If gintDocuSignEnviron = 1 Or gintDocuSignEnviron = 2 Then
    strURL = "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token"
            
    strAuthorization = gstrIntegrationKey & ":" & gstrSandboxSecretKey
                            
ElseIf gintDocuSignEnviron >= 3 And gintDocuSignEnviron <= 6 Then
    strURL = "https://account.docusign.com/oauth/token"
    
    strAuthorization = gstrIntegrationKey & ":" & gstrNA4SecretKey
    
Else
    Stop
End If

strAuthorization = Trim(Base64EncodeString(strAuthorization))

Set objHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

objHTTP.Open "POST", strURL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type: ", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept: ", "application/json"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization: ", "Basic " & strAuthorization
objHTTP.send "grant_type=authorization_code&code=" & strCode
```

Also, does the secret key expire or is it limited to one use?

Thanks

Ken

Answer (score 0):

Been a long time since I wrote VBA, but I think your header name arguments should not have the trailing colons and spaces; that is, they should just look like:

```
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & strAuthorization
```

If that still doesn't work, try to craft the request in a separate tool (e.g. cURL or Postman) and see if you can get it to succeed that way. The auth code expires after 2 minutes though, so work fast. And it likely expires after one use, too.